# Why does my displacement look inverted in Eevee?

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, displacement

I downloaded a BRICK texture pack, which came with a diffuse image and several maps.

(This is all in eevee).

After experimenting a little, I decided to use the diffuse and displacement maps. I applied them onto a cylinder, starting with the diffuse image. It looked ok, sorta like this:

[image]

Then I proceeded to apply the displacement map, which gave me this:

[image]

I was satisfied with the look, but then I noticed this:

[image]

The texture on a certain PART (around 30% of the curved face) of the cylinder seems to have been "inverted" in the image above. All the bricks in this section clearly seem to "go into" the screen, rather than "come out" of it.

Here is my question: What is causing the issue, and how would I go about fixing it?

Also, if it is of any help, I noticed two jarring "lines" enclosing the inverted part of the cylinder (kinda like two boundaries), which, interestingly, had no shadows, meaning they aren't affected by the displacement map. One of the "lines" looked like this, (with the inverted part on the left, and the ok part to the right):

[image]

The other line is not in this shot. It's located a little to the side, and looks exactly the same.

P.S.: the file - [image]

Comment: Dunno if this will be of any use but can't u use the invert node between the texture and the displacement node?

Comment: @moonboots here you go, should have the files now

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 I dunno about that node, but I'm assuming it'll invert the entire map on the whole cylinder, but the problem only exists on a small part of the cylinder's surface.

Comment: it looks like Displacement doesn't work very well in Eevee, especially if the Scale value of your Displacement node is high, maybe lower this value; or plug your DISP Image Texture into the Heigtht socket of a Bump node that you plug into the Normal socket of the Principled BSDF

Comment: @moonboots I would agree with you if it weren't for the fact that I've noticed this Very same issue in cycles, sooooooo idk what's up with that. As for the bump node thing I'll definitely try it sometime later, (I'm in the middle of something rn). Anyway, thanks for helping me out man, cheers :D

Comment: yes you're right so it must have to do with some limits of the displacement maps, maybe someone will explain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you are using a **Vector Displacement Node**. For traditional displacement, connect the texture to the height input of a regular **Displacement Node** and/or the height input of a **Bump Node**. You can use either one, or both, however, for EEVEE, I find the Bump Node arrangement on its own to be sufficient 99% of the time.

[image: Displace]

Comment: Ahaha, that was easier than I imagined. Thanks a lot mate, you are a lifesaver! Now, excuse me while I go learn about the three nodes, and the differences between them. 
Cheers! :D

Comment: ahah that was it